# GraphQL queries and mutations over WebSockets in Nest.js

Tags: websocket, graphql, nestjs

How can i make all queries and mutations in Nest over WebSockets only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable full WebSocket transport:

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  subscriptions: {
    'graphql-ws': true
  },
})
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions

Comment: Does this setting actually send queries and mutations over WebSockets?  The docs make it seem like only subscriptions are sent over WebSockets.  Does anyone have any code examples with mutations being sent over WebSockets?